# Battle.net complete white screen

Tags: ati

My battle.net shows a complete white screen, so I'm not able to do anything with it. I have Ubuntu, an AMD GPU and an i3 CPU.

When starting battle.net from the command line, I'm getting following error message:

> err:d3d:load_numbered_arrays >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_OPERATION (0x502) from Loading numbered arrays @ state.c /
>
> 4241

Answer (score 4):

This problem has been reported originally on WINEDB app site of Bugzilla with bug [37347](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37347).  However, it later turned out that the culprit was [described here.](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84651)  Then finally a open bounty was placed on this most unnerving problem.  The problem was indeed solved and put into Master.

Thank the happy people of the Linux community who did find a solution.  It's a tricky one, so do not get discouraged.  I had an immense amount of trouble at first.

First off you will need several tools to get the job done.
First off is the nicely made package call Autotools.
There is a list needed for dependencies required to compile Mesa and Install it:

[Python 2.6 or later](http://www.python.org/)

[Python mako module .7.3 or later](http://www.makotemplates.org/)

[dri2proto 2.6 or later](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/releases/individual/proto/)

[LibDRM 2.4.33 or later](http://dri.freedesktop.org/libdrm/)

Other dependencies required in building can be installed using the apt command in the terminal 
`python-dev` (in case you need the development headers, if not, nothing is needed), `python-mako`
`x11proto-dri2-dev`
`libdrm-dev`

Extract using

```
tar vxz ~$Whateverdiryourfilesarein/each one linked
```

Install using `./configure` and `make` commands

For Autotools

Simply open up a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
sudo apt-get install automake
```

At which point you will now be able to compile everything.  So now, in the terminal type:

`tar xvzf ~$whateverfolderitsin/Mesa10.4`

`./autogen.sh --enable-dri`

once that is done, type:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot the system and now everything should work.  Autotools is a pain but will be well worth the time later on in life.

Comment: my terminal say that , bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: You extracted Mesa first @CRuise

Comment: I have all that Python 2.6 or later

Python mako module .7.3 or later

dri2proto 2.6 or later

LibDRM 2.4.33 or later
 i did sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
sudo apt-get install automake that then the mesa thing i dont know how to do it.?D:

Comment: I edited my answer to help you along

Comment: Hey i did everything but still dont work , http://i.imgur.com/9C7ASB8.png help ;(

Comment: Regarding your dependencies, I think they can be installed using `apt-get`. They are, respectively: `python-dev` (in case you need the development headers, if not, nothing is needed), `python-mako`, `x11proto-dri2-dev` and `libdrm-dev`.

Comment: It might be a bit of a risk, but the [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) contains the latest Mesa (10.5.0), and the patch was already applied in 10.4.0 RC4, so the PPA might make things a lot simpler.

Comment: Still not wokring tryed everything again .