# Battle.net Launcher Completely White (Wine)

Tags: wine

I installed the Battle.net launcher following these instructions:

[How to install Battle.Net and run Blizzard games on Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114328/how-to-install-battle-net-and-run-blizzard-games-on-ubuntu-18-10)

But after logging in, the entire window is white. There is also a little secondary window showing I don't recall from previous installations.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RyDu.png

I found an older question about this here

[Battle.net complete white screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581049/battle-net-complete-white-screen)

which I followed. But sadly that didn't seem to help at all. Everything looks exactly as before. Curiously the log-in screen looks perfectly fine, as did the actual installation progress.

Comment: try using lutris for wine here is the link for battle.net it works on my system https://lutris.net/games/battlenet/

Comment: ^^plus one.  using Lutris it will install and run correctly

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you! I'll have fun playing around with this for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in accordance with the comment under my question I installed Lutris, and it works great.